# Eclipse projects: files to be subversioned

Tags: eclipse, svn

I created an Eclipse project and now I want to put it on my SVN repository. Which files should I put on ignore list? There are many files that I don't know what they are used for. There are folders like .history, .root, .safetable, .log, .settings ... and many .index files, also some .running files. Can I put all that to ignore list? Do you know which extensions/folders can always be on ignore?

Thanks.

Comment: I just commit `src` folder and avoid committing any file/folder starting with a dot `.` But heavily depends on your folder structure, my belief is _commit source only_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that any file whose name is starting with a dot should not be versioned. Most commonly such files refer to Eclipse settings which are not project-relevant.

Now, the .project and the .classpath files, in a Java project, are quite "project dependant" and I usually include them.

To get a more precise answer you should specify which project type you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very dependent on your project. Committing the source is a good thing however it'll force new developer to recreate the project environment which can be painful. If you are using Maven with the m2eclipse plugin committing only `src` and `pom.xml` is a good approach as it only takes a few minutes to recreate the Eclipse environment from src and `pom.xml`.

On the other hand it is ok to commit `.classpath` and `.project` **but** that also means extra work such as never using external jar directly but through variables or user library, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have time to experiment, why not check in everything, have a colleague check out the project, and see what throws up errors? Anything that references paths outside the project is likely to fail if your colleague doesn't organize her harddrive the same as yours. Those things should be changed to reference variables, or not placed under version control.

Let your colleague build the project, run the IDE through its paces, and then sync up to the repository to see what changed. Files that are volatile, run time logs, and temp files should be omitted. Anything that makes it easier for another developer to setup the project and get running should be included. Taking time to experiment will help you gain a better understanding how your project is setup.

Basically, you want to avoid checking in anything derived from source (like .class files in a Java project) or anything that every developer would have to change for their local environment, like a file with absolute references outside the project directory. One approach I have used in the past for handling configuration files that require customization by developers is to include a copy of the file, usually with extra comments, with a .example extension. Make it clear in a README or other documentation which example files need to be customized and what the "real" name for the file should be. Also include he "real" file name in the svnignore list so it doesn't get checked in and overwrite everyone's local customizations.

To address your specific examples:

> .history, .root, .safetable, .log,
>   .settings ... and many .index files,
>   also some .running

.settings is one you'll have to experiment with. If you have settings, such as code style or formatting guidelines, that all developers need to follow, then it can be handy to have those under version control, but some other settings may not be appropriate for all developers. The other examples are not familiar to me, possibly because they are associated with a type of Eclipse project I don't work with.

Comment: It just occurred to me what the .index files might be. Are you looking at your workspace directory instead of the project directory? There would likely be .index files under your workspace's .metadata folder.